# Disable "Firefox must send information that will repeat any action" dialog box

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I'm using the extension [Check4Change](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/check4change/) on Firefox to check for changes on a webpage so I can book an appointment. Unfortunately, the page is set up so that upon refresh the following box pops up:

> To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.

Is there any way to disable this in Firefox's about:config settings or elsewhere? What about solutions in other browsers? Chrome used to have a `-disable-prompt-on-repost` command line flag, but this has been deprecated for some time.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. The `disable-prompt-on-repost` was the only way to obtain what you wished for.

Answer (score 1):

I changed "dom.confirm_repost.testing.always_accept" to "true" in about:config and it worked. It's Firefox 91.13.0esr (64-bit).